# When would InitializeCulture be called

Tags: asp.net

I found many pages of my maintenance website inherits a base page which overrides **InitializeCulture** to customize some globalization settings.

Is this method called **every time** for any incoming request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture.aspx it's going to get called very early (like, even before controls are added early) in the page-initialization process. So yes, it would be called each time an aspx page that derives from your base page is requested.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if InitializeCulture is called on a base page it will be called on every page that inherits that base page **and** on every incoming request.

You can always try putting a line like:
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("intializing culture");
Inside the function call. It will appear at the top of every page that inherits the class to prove to you that it's always being called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and for each [BrowserLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link) update too, as I have just found out. (Using Visual Studio 2015 and Google Chrome today.)

It this annoys you, you can [disable Browserlink](http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/).